# How to retrieve specific data from json array via retrofit2 using gson parsing

Tags: android, json, arraylist, gson, retrofit2

Here is the JSON response from a server (which i cannot change the structure of)

My issues are as follows:
1. The data changes based on the query so sometimes the Primary posts & Secondary Posts are an array and sometimes they are an object/ string.

2. How would i go about retrieving a value from Address without getting the whole structure?
   Eg.

   - only retrieve Email & post code strings from MainAddress
   - only retrieve Address1 from Website & Twitter

```
{
    "Members": {
    "Member": {
    "@First_Id": "000",
    "@Second_Id": "000",
    "@Third_Id": "000",
    "@Fourth_Id": "000",
    "DisplayAs": "Title FirstName LastName",
    "ListAs": "LastName, Title FirstName",
    "FullTitle": "Title Title FirstName LastName Title",
    "PreviousName": null,
    "DateOfBirth": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DateOfDeath": {
    "@xsi:nil": "true",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    },
    "Gender": "M OR F",
    "Party": {
    "@Id": "4",
    "#text": "Party Name"
    },
    "House": "House Name",
    "MemberFrom": "Area Name",
    "HouseStartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "HouseEndDate": {
    "@xsi:nil": "true",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    },
    "CurrentStatus": {
    "@Id": "0",
    "@IsActive": "True",
    "Name": "Current Member",
    "Reason": null,
    "StartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "Addresses": {
    "Address": [
    {
    "@Type_Id": "6",
    "Type": "Website",
    "IsPreferred": "False",
    "IsPhysical": "False",
    "Note": null,
    "Address1": "https://www.example.co.uk"
    },
    {
    "@Type_Id": "1",
    "Type": "MainAddress",
    "IsPreferred": "False",
    "IsPhysical": "True",
    "Note": null,
    "Address1": "Line 1",
    "Address2": "Line 2",
    "Address3": "Line 3",
    "Address4": null,
    "Address5": "County Name",
    "Postcode": "Postcode",
    "Phone": "000 0000 000",
    "Fax": "000 0000 000",
    "Email": "example@email.co.uk",
    "OtherAddress": null
    },
    {
    "@Type_Id": "7",
    "Type": "Twitter",
    "IsPreferred": "False",
    "IsPhysical": "False",
    "Note": null,
    "Address1": "https://twitter.com/twitter_name"
    },
    {
    "@Type_Id": "4",
    "Type": "Address2",
    "IsPreferred": "False",
    "IsPhysical": "True",
    "Note": null,
    "Address1": "Line1",
    "Address2": "Line2",
    "Address3": "Line3",
    "Address4": "Line4",
    "Address5": null,
    "Postcode": "Postcode",
    "Phone": "0000 000 000",
    "Fax": null,
    "Email": "example2@email.co.uk",
    "OtherAddress": null
    }
    ]
    },
    "PrimaryPosts": {
    "PrimaryPost": [
    {
    "@Id": "000",
    "Name": "Name",
    "ProperName": "The Name",
    "StartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Note": null,
    "EndNote": null,
    "IsJoint": "False",
    "IsUnpaid": "False",
    "Email": null,
    "FormerName": "Name"
    },
    {
    "@Id": "000",
    "Name": "Name",
    "ProperName": "The Name",
    "StartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Note": null,
    "EndNote": null,
    "IsJoint": "False",
    "IsUnpaid": "False",
    "Email": null,
    "FormerName": "Name"
    }
    ]
    },
    "FormerPosts": {
    "FormerPost": [
    {
    "@Id": "000",
    "Name": "Name",
    "ProperName": "The Name",
    "StartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Note": null,
    "EndNote": null,
    "IsJoint": "False",
    "IsUnpaid": "False",
    "Email": null
    },
    {
    "@Id": "000",
    "Name": "Name",
    "ProperName": "The Name",
    "StartDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Note": null,
    "EndNote": null,
    "IsJoint": "False",
    "IsUnpaid": "False",
    "Email": null
    }
    ]
    },
    "BiographyEntries": {
    "BiographyEntry": [
    {
    "@Category_Id": "1",
    "Category": "Interest 1",
    "Entry": "Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4"
    },
    {
    "@Category_Id": "2",
    "Category": "Interest 2",
    "Entry": "Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

My current code for parsing is:

```
    public class Main Activity extends AppcompatActivity {

    private DataCallAPI dataCallAPI;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.co.uk/data/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    dataCallAPI = retrofit.create(DataCallAPI.class);
    Call<RootObject> call = dataCallAPI.getMember(postcode);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<RootObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RootObject> call, Response<RootObject> response) {
        Log.d("JSON Log D", "onResponse: Server Response" + response.toString()+ "\n\n");

    RootObject callData= response.body();

    ArrayList<Address> addressList = 
        response.body().getMembers().getMember().getAddresses().getAddress();
        for( int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {

        Log.d("JSON Log D", "onResponse: \n" +
        addressList.get(i).getType() + " Address: " + addressList.get(i).getAddress1() + "\n" +
        addressList.get(i).getType() + " Number: " + addressList.get(i).getPhone() + "\n" +
        addressList.get(i).getType() + " Email: " + addressList.get(i).getEmail() + "\n" +
        "------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RootObject> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("JSON Log E", "onFailure: Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage() );
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
    }
```

I have setup models for all the POJO that I can, but the model for Addresses which contains either ArrayList or Object will fail dependant on the json data being returned.

```
    package com.example.retrofittutorialbuild.Model;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.example.retrofittutorialbuild.Model.Address.Address;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Addresses {

        @SerializedName("Address")
        @Expose
        private ArrayList<Address> address = null;

        public ArrayList<Address> getAddress() { return address;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Addresses{" +
        "address=" + address +
        '}';
    }
}
```

The current response i am getting is:

```
2020-01-31 11:18:35.058 27987-27987/com.example.retrofittutorialbuild D/JSON Log D: onResponse: 
    Website Address: http://www.exampleurl.co.uk
    Website Number: null
    Website Email: null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-31 11:18:35.058 27987-27987/com.example.retrofittutorialbuild D/JSON Log D: onResponse: 
    MainAddress Address: example address
    MainAddress Number: 000 0000 000
    MainAddress Email: email@example.co.uk
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-31 11:18:35.058 27987-27987/com.example.retrofittutorialbuild D/JSON Log D: onResponse: 
    Twitter Address: https://twitter.com/example
    Twitter Number: null
    Twitter Email: null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-31 11:18:35.058 27987-27987/com.example.retrofittutorialbuild D/JSON Log D: onResponse: 
    Address2 Address: example address
    Address2 Number: 000 0000 000
    Address2 Email: email@example.co.uk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can check type and get value easily if key are available in response

Comment: Thanks for replying Avinash, could you show how i would do that? been searching for ages and not finding a way forward with the current code im using :(

Comment: what you want to do with JSON  can you explain it, i don't understand your exactly problem because your result is fine.

Comment: if your key is change at run time then you can use Object type of key and check it is array or object or something else .and get value from it by json parshing.

Comment: Hi Avinash, sorry for the late response.

I am basically trying to extract only the relevant values from the Address ArrayList so i can assign them to a database to be used across the rest of the App.

For example i need:

From Type_ID: 1
- email
- phone

From Type_ID: 6
- address1

From Type_ID: 7
- address1

From Type_ID: 4
- phone
- email